# A question in algorithm of decoding with a binary hamming code

Tags: coding-theory

I have following question in the algorithm on page 85 of Xing and Ling.

[image]

> Question : Why number of coset leaders are $2^r$  and why each of their weight is $\leq $ 1?

Kindly give some explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything mysterious going on here.

This code correctly decodes messages which have experience $0$ errors or one single error.

Messages which experienced the same error reside in a common coset.

The coset leader is, by definition, the word of least weight in the coset.

Obviously a word of weight $1$ in one of these error cosets is of least weight.  (If it had the (unique) word of zero weight, it would mean we are in the no-error coset.)

So there you go: the leader for the coset of no-errors (the zero vector) plus the vectors of weight $1$ and length $n$ provide a complete collection of coset leaders for correctable errors.

Since the parity check matrix has columns (or rows, depending on your perspective) that are just the nonzero binary words of length $r$, there are $2^r-1$ of them.  Since we know there are $n$ of them, $2^r-1=n$, hence the equation they gave.